# Continue numbering of paragraphs after a new section

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx, paragraphs

I need to numerate the paragraphs of my document, divided by section, without the number of paragraph changed with the new defined by section, I hope that this example will better explain what I have just described. I am using lyx, any solution that can create that type of document is well accepted.

1. First Section

   1 first paragraph

   2 second paragraph
2. First Section

   3 third paragraph

   4 forth paragraph

I managed to write that code but the paragraph still reset its number, here is my try.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have subsections or by "paragraph" do you mean the next level of heading down from section?

Comment: i mean that what i have inside the two sections (if it is a subsection it does not matter) must follow a common numbering as you can see from the example. Thank you.

Comment: yes but the natural thing to do for the version shown would be to use \subsection for your paragraphs and define subsection not to be reset by \section. but if you have subsections that do reset and want the next level down not to reset then that would be subsubsection.

Comment: Ok I understand, so is it possible to made what i want with subsection and subsubsection?

Comment: sorry I really don't know lyx,  (a lyx user can probably see your question and help) perhaps that code is inserted into a tex group (which would not work. you could put those lines into `abc.sty` and then tell lyx to use `\usepackage{abc}` i assume you can tell it which packages to load?

Comment: i put it in the preamble but the program does not compile, but i think that i can manage to make your solution work, i would only want to make the number of paragraph incremental with the code you write in your answer

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni can you please post a minimal example .lyx file (it is just a text file so you can copy/paste into your question), with your most recent attempt? Then ping me (using `@`) and I'll take a look. For more information on MWE, see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
\subsection{}
xxxx
\subsection{}
xxxx
\section{bbb}
\subsection{}
xxxx
\subsection{}
xxxx

\end{document}
```

or....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

\begin{enumerate}
\item xxxx
\item xxxx
\end{enumerate}

\section{bbb}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]

\item xxxx
\item xxxx
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's `chngcntr` that does it better.

Comment: @egreg feel free to write a competing answer:-)

Comment: ok but how can i manage to implement the first with lyx, i try with texcode but it does not work because i have the section numbered with the poin like 1.1, 1.2 and 2.1, 2.1. i would like to obtain section like 1,2,3,4 separted by 1 and 2

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni you need to get the lines that I put in the preamble into the preamble generated by lyx. i have no idea how to do that in lyx (I do not have the system installed) but I understand it has a way to insert tex code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edit the question, any advice?